# Yii2 model rules match validation

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

In model rules I have this rule:

```
[
  ['field1', 'field2,]
  'match',
  'pattern' => "/^[а-яА-ЯіІїЇєЄa-zA-Z\s\`\'\-\,]*$/u",
]
```

On form submit this rule works fine. But on client side it's not working. In console I see error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[а-яА-ЯіІїЇєЄa-zA-Z\s\`'-,]*$/: Invalid escape
```

Why this rule doesn't works on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape with double slash fixes client side without crashing server side

```
[
  ['field1', 'field2,]
  'match',
  'pattern' => "/^[а-яА-ЯіІїЇєЄa-zA-Z\s\\\`\\\'-\\\,]*$/u",
]
```